# Kaa networking and protocols

Tags: kaa

We are investigating adding the Kaa client to our products and using the Kaa server operationally, and we have some questions in the networking and protocol area.  Our main concern is having the IoT device access the IoT server through the Internet without being blocked by the firewall at the IoT device in a "typical" environment.  For this reason we see that HTTP/HTTPS using port 80/443 is often used.

Do you believe that most of the IoT device will communicate because most firewalls allow all outgoing traffic?

Or do you think that most end users will have to explicitly configure a firewall rule for the IoT device?

What was the rationale for using the port numbers 9889/9888 and 9999/9997?

Can these port numbers be reasonablely modified?  If so, where and how?

Is there a specification of the Kaa TCP protocol?

Thank You
Keith Krajewski

Answer (score 0):

About Kaa TCP protocol use [official documentation page](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Transports)

you can change ports of bootstrap and operations services in this files:

- bootstrap-http-transport.config
- bootstrap-tcp-transport.config
- operations-http-transport.config
- operations-tcp-transport.config